# Why is the LINQ "apply-to-all" method named Select?

Tags: linq, naming-conventions

When I read code that uses `Select` I think "select-all-where".
When I read code that uses `Map` I think "this-to-that" or "apply-to-all".
I can't be the only person that feels the name `Select` is confusing.

[Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's really identical to map from functional languages. The reason it's named `Select` is that it's designed to be used as a part of LINQ which uses SQL-like keywords.

```
from item in collection
where item.Value == someValue
select item.Name
```

is translated to:

```
collection.Where(item => item.Value == someValue)
          .Select(item => item.Name)
```

it would be a little inconsistent if `Select` was named `Map`; something like:

```
collection.Filter(item => item.Value == someValue)
          .Map(item => item.Name)
```

In fact, many people use LINQ without having heard of functional programming at all. To them, LINQ is a method to retrieve data objects and query them easily (like SQL queries are). To them, `Select` and `Where` make perfect sense. Much more than `Map` and `Filter`.

Comment: Makes complete sense. If I really cared that much I could wrap `Where` and `Select` in extension methods.

Comment: Good answer. I actually used "Select" without LINQ, but it's much clearer as a LINQ expression.

Comment: Thanks, great answer.  Out of context it doesn't make any sense, but this helps explain it.

Comment: This is a small difference that is worth pointing out: in LINQ, the application of the map ("select") is deferred.

So for example, if you do:

    `collection.Select( x => x*x )`
    `collection[0] // x*x not applied.`

In order to force evaluation, you can force the creation of a new list:

    `collection = collection.Select( x => x*x ).ToList()`

Answer (score 4):

At first `Select` seemed little confusing for me too, but it was only a matter of time. Mehrdad tells you a good reason for `Select`. Other than that I feel `Select` conveys the immutability aspect of `Linq` much better. Not that `Map` would mean it's mutating the original structure, but `Select` states it much clearer. It tells you're not touching the original list but merely selecting from it to form another list.

It goes with other naming as well like `Where`. When you call `collection.Filter` it gives you an idea that you're filtering on that particular collection, or at least the first time. In the end it's all a matter of getting familiarized. Though in the beginning I was so annoyed by the `Linq` namings, now I feel MS team has got it the most correct.

Comment: +1 for "`Select` states it much clearer". One has to think outside SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

One of the major reasons Select comes last is to make Intellisense work. By putting the source of the sequence first (from statement), Intellisense can work properly.

Comment: how is this related to the question?