# What is the C# equivalent of map function in Haskell

Tags: c#

map function in Haskell has two input parameters. The first parameter is a function and second parameter is a list. The map function applies the function passed as input parameter to all the elements in the list and returns a new list.

Is there a C# equivalent to this functionality?

Comment: You may want to check out F#. It bridges the gap between C# and Haskell.

Comment: And to answer a question you didn't ask, the Haskell equivalent of binding the "sequence" monad is called SelectMany in C#. See Wes Dyer's great article on this for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2008/01/11/the-marvels-of-monads.aspx

Comment: Not really.  It is more like "OCaml for .NET".

Comment: Not to mention that all of the ML-family languages (including F# and Haskell) arguably have more in common with each other than with any C-family language; anyone who can handle F# can probably handle Haskell or OCaml as well.

Comment: @jrockway, @camccann: I am not talking about the syntax of the language. I mean the fact that F# doesn't force you to always use a pure functional style.

Comment: Possibly related: [C#/Linq: Apply a mapping function to each element in an IEnumerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7187409/456814).

Comment: Updated link - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wesdyer/2008/01/10/the-marvels-of-monads/

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`Select`

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

See my question [Why is the LINQ "apply-to-all" method named `Select`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113258/why-is-the-linq-apply-to-all-method-named-select) (Only if you are curious as it is not directly related).

Comment: Thanks...This is a bit counter intuitive, I was thinking Select would filter rows from a collection.

Comment: I really hope you check out my question.

Comment: BM: Filtering comes from Where.

Answer (score 23):

Another alternative to `Select` and `SelectMany` is to write your own extension method.

```
public static IEnumerable<U> Map<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> s, Func<T, U> f)
{
  foreach (var item in s)
    yield return f(item);
}
```

Thanks Wes Dyer for this sweet extension method! :)
See [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/18/why-functional-programming-is-important-in-a-mixed-environment.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 15):

Since `Select` and `SelectMany` were already mentioned, I'll answer an additional question you didn't ask: `fold` is found as [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx).

Now everyone reading this should be fully equipped to go be That Guy who writes Language X using Language Y idioms... so for the sake of your fellow C# programmers, don't get *too* carried away.

Comment: Now camccann, there is nothing wrong with throwing a functional wrench into your toolbox even though you are imperatively hammering nails. You may have to tighten a few bolts.

Comment: @camccan Functional C# is really pretty good. Just because the language isn't strictly functional doesn't mean that most .net programmers wouldn't hugely benefit from building things a *lot* more functionally.

Comment: Using the functional programming features that C# offers is a great idea. Forcing C# into functional idioms that it doesn't support well (say, curried partial application as is so popular in Haskell), on the other hand, will probably give you a headache, obfuscate your code, and annoy anyone else who has to work with it.

Answer (score 3):

How about [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It looks like Closest to Map.