# C#/Linq: Apply a mapping function to each element in an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been looking for a way to transform each element of an `IEnumerable` into something else using a mapping function (in a Linq-compatible way) but I haven't found anything.

For a (very simple) example, it should be able to do something like

```
IEnumerable<int> integers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<string> strings = integers.Transform(i => i.ToString());
```

But I haven't found anything. I mean, it's pretty straightforward to write an extension method that accomplishes that (basically, all it requires is wrapping the source `Enumerator` into a new class and then writing a bit of boilerplate code for delegating the calls to it), but I would have expected this to be a fairly elementary operation, and writing it myself feels like reinventing the wheel - I can't shake the feeling that there may be a built-in way which I should be using, and I've just been too blind to see it.

So... is there something in Linq that allows me to do what I described above?

Comment: Possibly related: [What is the C# equivalent of map function in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2142935/456814).

Answer (score 261, accepted):

You can just use the [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) extension method:

```
IEnumerable<int> integers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<string> strings = integers.Select(i => i.ToString());
```

Or in LINQ syntax:

```
IEnumerable<int> integers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var strings = from i in integers
              select i.ToString();
```

Comment: Ah! I knew there had to be a way. A bit of the old "Forest/Trees Visual Occlusion Problem", I guess :)

Comment: Be aware that if your map has side-effects you may run into trouble since the body of the `Select()` won't necessarily be executed until it's enumerated. Not that it's a great idea to do that, but there may be some situations where you may need to add `ToList()` to force it to evaluate the entire list.

Comment: Is it not more correct to call the one form 'linq query syntax' and the other form 'linq method syntax'?

Comment: Actually both are Linq syntax types, the first one is called Method syntax and the second one is called Query syntax. Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq

Answer (score 39):

You're looking for [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) which can be used to transform\project the input sequence:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = integers.Select(i => i.ToString());
```

Comment: To be fair it's supposed to match SQL (where the latter set of terms are common terminology)

Comment: It's pretty annoying. I'm trying to learn functional programming... but have to unlearn 10 years of LINQ terms. I need a translation guide. I wonder of Google translate could help...