# Retrieve List<Object> to List<String>

Tags: c#, list

Currently, I have a `List<object>` like this: `List<USER>`.

In `User` class, I have column named `UserName`.

I want to retrieve this column to `List<string>`.

How can it work without using `foreach` for `List<USER>`?

Thanks.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187409/c-linq-apply-a-mapping-function-to-each-element-in-an-ienumerable

Answer (score 9):

You can use LINQ:

```
List<string> userNames = users.Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
```

Comment: Important to note is that internally, this is still solved with a foreach loop... but then again, there's no way to get around that.

Comment: @Tobberoth: Yes, of course LINQ cannot perform magic ;) But it can increase readability which is more important than a few milliseconds anyway.

Comment: woa, thank Tim a lot. It saved my time a lot.

Comment: @user3011414: You may want to accept an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tim Schmelter post:

For casting  `IEnumerable<object>` to `IEnumerable<USER>` you may use `Cast<T>` or `OfType<T>` method.

This can be written as follows:

```
var userNames = users.Cast<USER>.Select(u => u.UserName).ToList();
```