# Map enumerator (not enumerable) type to an enumerator of another type

Tags: c#, enumerator

How can I transform an `IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` to an `IEnumerator<TKey>` containing the key from the key-value pair?

More generally, how can I transform `IEnumerator<TSource>` to `IEnumerator<TTarget>` if there is a conversion from `TSource` to `TTarget`?

Note that this question is not seeking information on how to enumerate an enumerator (use `MoveNext` and `Current`), or how to transform an enumerator to an enumerable (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029612/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-convert-ienumerator-to-ienumerable)), or how to transform an enumerable to an enumerator (just call `GetEnumerator()` on the `IEnumerable<T>`), or how to map an enumerable to another type (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187409/c-linq-apply-a-mapping-function-to-each-element-in-an-ienumerable)).

I have provided my own proposed answers as answers, but of course I'm happy to hear about other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that I like better is as follows. (One could also define it as a `struct` instead of a `class`, for example to reduce heap allocation.)

```
public class TransformEnumerator<TSource, TTarget> : IEnumerator<TTarget>
{
    IEnumerator<TSource> SourceEnumerator;
    Func<TSource, TTarget> TransformFunc;

    public TransformEnumerator(IEnumerator<TSource> sourceEnumerator, Func<TSource, TTarget> transformFunc)
    {
        SourceEnumerator = sourceEnumerator;
        TransformFunc = transformFunc;
    }

    public TTarget Current => TransformFunc(SourceEnumerator.Current);

    object IEnumerator.Current => TransformFunc(SourceEnumerator.Current);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SourceEnumerator.Dispose();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return SourceEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        SourceEnumerator.Reset();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach, using a `static class`:

```
public static class TransformEnumerator2<TSource, TTarget>
{
    public static IEnumerator<TTarget> GetEnumerator(IEnumerator<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TTarget> transformFunc)
    {
        return (IEnumerator<TTarget>)GetEnumerable(source, transformFunc);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TTarget> GetEnumerable(IEnumerator<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TTarget> transformFunc)
    {
        while (source.MoveNext())
            yield return transformFunc(source.Current);
    }
}
```

Note that the `GetEnumerable` method is private. In a public API, the client expects to be able to use an enumerable multiple times, but the enumerable here can be used only once. However, an Enumerator is expected to be used only once, since the behavior of Reset is undefined, so this accomplishes its goal.